# Find all Nodes and Relations up to a defined path length within Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm stuck with a problem returning all nodes and relationships within the following pattern:

```
(a:LABEL_A)-[:REL_A]->(x:LABEL_B)-[r:REL_B*1..n]->(y:LABEL_B)<-(b:LABEL_A)
WHERE a.prop IN [Array of Strings] AND b.prop IN [Array of Strings]
```

The "Array of Strings" at both ends of the path is the same. The result I'm looking for is a list of all the paths in-between a group of nodes up to a defined depth with all the properties of the "in-between" nodes and the properties of the "in-between" relationships

The result I'm struggling to achieve is shown in the following structure:

a.prop, x.prop, r.prop, y.prop, b.prop : in the case the path length is 1

up to...

a.prop, x.prop, r(1).prop, in-between_node(1).prop, r(2).prop, in-between_node(2).prop, ..., y.prop, b.prop : in the case the path length is n

Is there an easy way to create this as a simple list output?

Any tip greatly appreciated

Krid

Comment: You can save a path to a variable when matching, like `MATCH p=(:A)-[..25]->(:B)`, and then you can convert the path to a list of nodes by using `RETURN NODES(p) as n`. Is this what you are looking for? (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#named-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to get the `path`s that match your pattern. Each path contains all the nodes and relationships (and their properties), in path order. For example, this query:

```
WITH ['b','c'] AS arrayOfStrings
MATCH path=(a:LABEL_A)-[:REL_A]->(x:LABEL_B)-[r:REL_B*1..5]->(y:LABEL_B)<--(b:LABEL_A)
WHERE a.prop IN arrayOfStrings AND b.prop IN arrayOfStrings
RETURN path;
```

will return a result such as this (where only one path was found):

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| path                                                                                                                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (:LABEL_A {prop: "c"})-[:REL_A {foo: "bar"}]->(:LABEL_B {foo: "baz"})-[:REL_B {fie: "foe"}]->(:LABEL_B {foo: "bax"})<-[:REL_A {foo: "fop"}]-(:LABEL_A {prop: "b"}) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```